# Download microsoft office documents functionality in openerp

Tags: python-2.7, download, odoo, docx, openerp-7

I want to implement the functionality of downloading an automatically generated word document. Similar to reports in the HR recruitment module of openerp. The functionality is available under Human resources -> recruitment -> Applications -> form view of any application on the top right side of the sheet you find the print interview button which downloads the survey.

I want a similar functionality however it should not be a report but a word document that is populated with data from the applicant such as his/her name date of applying, ... ect. I already have a python function that can populate Microsoft word documents with data from a given dictionary, but the main problem I am facing is how to make the generated document downloadable on click from the user. The document doesn't need to be associated with the applicant so there is no field for the document to be downloaded.

Comment: Which library do you use ? If you can generate the docx in a file, than I don't see what the problem has to do with docx.

Comment: I don't use a library I just use the openXml standard and xml builtin library of python to manipulate the data of the docx file to generate a new one with the modifications